# Query Azure SQL from Nintex 2013

Tags: azure-sql-database, sharepoint-2013, nintex-workflow

I was wondering if it's possible to connect to an Azure SQL database from a Nintex Workflow running on Sharepoint 2013 on premise. I have multiple workflows where I connect to an on premise MS SQL server, but cannot get this to work with Azure SQL.
I've tried using many different connection strings, but keep getting "Unexpected SQL error occured". I know that the account I use has access to the database, so there might be other issues like firewall settings.

However, before I start messing with the firewall, can anyone tell me if it is even possible to connect to Azure SQL from Nintex 2013?

Comment: You could ref this tutorials: https://community.nintex.com/t5/Community-Blogs/Creating-Microsoft-SQL-Server-Connection-to-SQL-Azure-from/ba-p/78632 and https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/fetch-data-from-azure-sql-database-using-nintex-workflow-nwc-nintex-workflow-cl/.  If it's helpful, I can post it as answer.

Comment: Thanks, but those tutorials are about Nintex Cloud. I'm working with Nintex 2013 which is on-premise

Comment: I guess it's not supported for now.

Answer (score 0):

I found that you have post the same [question](https://community.nintex.com/t5/Nintex-for-SharePoint/Query-Azure-SQL-from-Nintex-Workflow-2013/td-p/121480) in Nintex 2013 forum.

Just for now, no one reply you and there's no documents talk about this, none Azure documents or Nintex documents.

So we may assume that on-premise Nintex 2013 doesn't support Azure SQL or Azure SQL database doesn't support Nintex 2013 for now.

Comment: Yes, I had hoped that someone on the Nintex forum might have the answer, but alas. Guess I'll have to contact Nintex support directly to get a definitive answer. Will post back when I get one. Thanks for your efforts!

Comment: @Teebs You're welcome, waiting for the update, have a nice day!